# I have a skypee virus in my SD card folder, i am very much worried about its potential to ruin my privacy, Help me

Tags: micro-sd, windows-mobile

Found it in my SD card folder and its contains are ((of folder "skypee") Autolt3.exe , Google.Ink , googleupdate.a3x , GoogleUpdate.Ink , Skypee.Ink , Windowsupdate.Ink

so I try to delete the folder it says it is write protected, how do I solve this issue ? Please help me, Autolt3 is the script loader and googleupdate.a3x is the script as far as I figured it out, will open the script and post here soon but before that someone give me an idea to remove this.

Comment: Which app are you trying to delete the folder with?

Comment: I have connected my phone to my laptop and I had to view hidden files to see the file "skypee" and tried to delete it from there normally Rowland Shaw

Comment: Was the SD Card used in an Android phone before?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be safe I'd suggest formatting the whole card using a pc. You'll probably need an adapter from microSD to regular size.

Otherwise you could do a hard reset of your phone and choose to format the SD card this way, but that requires more effort.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion but I want to specifically solve this issue, and not resetting my whole phone, I would have done that long back if I wanted to :)

Comment: Then move your apps and data to your phone first, format the SD card and move your data back over to the card afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried right clicking on the folder in Windows explorer and unchecking the read-only attribute?

Can you reach the microSD card via  a DOS prompt?

If so you can run an

```
attrib -h driveletter:\path\foldername
```

to remove the hidden attribute

```
attrib -r driveletter:\path\foldername
```

to remove the read only attribute.

You should be able to delete the files then via a dos prompt or in explorer.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to delete any shortcut virus completely.If it replicates itself then i would suggest you to read that post final solution.

First of all, click on my computer icon>tools>folder options>view.
uncheck hide protected... buttons and click on the show... radio button.
Press ok.

Now open each drive.You must see some hidden folders/files in the infected drives/mmc.

Now open the skypee folder which must be hidden.you will find a hidden skypee folder in it which contains some files especially autoit3(.exe).
Copy its name(auto...) and then delete it.Go to the start menu and click on Run.Type "regedit.exe" without quotes.Press enter to open it.From its menu click on find and paste the strings that you copied previously. Click on the find button.Thereafter delete those files containing that string.Click on find next button in regedit and do the same job.

N.B :

1.FIRST OF ALL, DELETE ALL HIDDEN FILE FROM YOUR SD CARD.
2. DON'T DOUBLE CLICK ON THE FILES OF THE SKYPEE FOLDER.
3.DON'T DELETE OR MODIFY ANY OTHER FILE IN REGEDIT EXCEPT THOSE FILES.
4.RESTART IS NOT REQUIRED. 
5.ALWAYS OPEN YOUR SD CARD USING EXPLORER.

Regards,
Joseph Paul

Comment: Um... Say, huh?